# Python 3.4 : Iterate through DataFrame column to match strings

Tags: loops, python-3.x, if-statement

## Data

```
915802|FINANCIAL INVESTORS TRUST|485BPOS|2015-03-19|edgar/data/915802/0001398344-15-001900.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|SC 13G|2015-03-27|edgar/data/1000045/0001436857-15-000014.txt
1000180|SANDISK CORP|4|2015-02-18|edgar/data/1000180/0001242648-15-000006.txt
1364688|Copano Pipelines/Upper Gulf Coast LLC|424B2|2015-02-24|edgar/data/1364688/0001047469-15-001126.txt
1634066|Robbins Nicholas W.|4|2015-03-25|edgar/data/1634066/0001628280-15-001965.txt
9984|BARNES GROUP INC|4|2015-02-13|edgar/data/9984/0000009984-15-000013.txt
1601072|Abengoa Yield plc|6-K|2015-01-16|edgar/data/1601072/0001193125-15-012191.txt
.....
```

I am currently trying this code where I try to match one of the specified values in  statList to the Data above and return the value that was matched and line which contained the specific value.

```
import pandas as pd

q1 = open('/home/aranjohn/StockRec/StockIndex/edgar.full-index.2015.QTR1.master.idx', 'r')

q2 = str.splitlines(q1.read())

statList = ['915802', '1000045', '1364688', '198749', '9984']

for eachStat in statList:
    for eachLine in q2:
        if eachStat in eachLine:
            print(eachStat, eachLine)
```

I understand the logical error here in which I end up returning every stat number and every line.  How would I return eachStat and then the line which contains eachStat?

## Desired Output

```
915802   edgar/data915802/0001398344-15-001900.txt
1000045  edgar/data/1000180/0001242648-15-000006.txt
1364688  edgar/data/1364688/0001047469-15-001126.txt
9984     edgar/data/9984/0000009984-15-000013.txt
```

Comment: Why do not use regexp?

Comment: Do you need specific 10-digit starred number?

Comment: There are thousands of lines in the txt file.  I need to search eachline for a list of specified values (so yes specific) and return the specified list value and the line containing that value

Comment: Just read this https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html   If you want more clear help, try to show your input and desired output.

Comment: I think the changes I made in the question will clear things up a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that logic of your code is ok. Works for me, with a few changes:

```
with open('your_data.dat') as f:
    data = str.splitlines(f.read())

statList = ['915802', '1000045', '1364688', '198749', '9984']

for eachStat in statList:
    for eachLine in data:
        if eachStat in eachLine:
            print (eachStat, eachLine.split('|')[-1])
```

And result is your desired output